# Why is ScrollView sometimes (!) not scrolling when scrollTo is called (in an onClick event)

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview

So I have this button (`ImageView` with `onClick` method) on the right side of the screen which when I pull it to the left extends into a `SeekBar` where you can select the time of day. To create this I have made a `ScrollView` with a horizontal `LinearLayout` with a see through view on the left and the "button"+`SeekBar` on the right (mostly outside of the screen). The "button" has an `OnTouch` and `OnClick` listener.

In the onTouch the scrollview is told to smoothScrollTo the correct location depending on where the finger is moving. When you move less than a certain threshold and release the onClick is called.

In the onClick I have told the scrollview to `smoothScrollTo` / `scrollTo` / `fullScroll`. The fullScroll didn't ever work. The smoothScrollTo works most of the time on one device (HTC Desire with Android 2.2.2) but never worked IN THE ONCLICK (?) on another device (Samsung Galaxy Tab (the old one) with Android 2.2). The scrollTo sometimes works on both devices... I am sure the `onClick` is called as I log that when it starts and also directly after telling the `ScrollView` to scroll.

I have tried posting the scrollTo to the `ScrollView` in a runnable and a delayed runnable:

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       scrollView.scrollTo(left, 0);
       Log.d("SomeTag", "The scroller should scroll to: "+left);
   }
}, 200);
```

But this worked just as often (so sometimes) as not posting it...

I am nonplussed. I am used to working with Android and used to different devices behaving differently, but I am not used to having the same call on the same device "sometimes" working and "sometimes" not... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930335/2153244).

`ScrollView.scrollTo()` may not working if some layout changes are being made when you called the method. And you are right, using `postDelayed()` you cannot guarantee that layout changes in will always finish within the same delay time.